# ¿Como enviar objeto de tipo clase en cuerpo de (HttpRequestMessage) metodo HttpPost?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

En una aplicación de tipo `WebApi`  tengo un método para crear los usuarios en `DB PostCreateUser`, este método recibe un objeto de tipo `User` que reside en el cuerpo de la solicitud, ahora necesito crear un método en mi aplicación de escritorio que consuma dicho método en la `Api...` escribí un método pero me devuelve error `400 BadRequest`

¿Que sera lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Método en la `Api`:

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostCreateUser([FromBody] User create)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            if (create == null)
                return response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);//Modelo incompleto 501

            EngineProyect Funcion = new EngineProyect();
            bool resultado = false;
            resultado = Funcion.CompareString(create.SignatureApp, EngineData.SignatureApp);
            if (!resultado)
                return response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed);//No es la firma 417

            EngineDb Metodo = new EngineDb();
            resultado = Metodo.InsertUser(create);
            if (!resultado)
            {
                response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);//No pudo crearse usuario 406
                response.Content = new StringContent(Metodo.Failure());//Informacion especifica del error
                return response;
            }

            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(EngineData.UrlBase + EngineData.EndPointLogin);
            return response;
        }
```

Método en mi aplicación de escritorio:

```
   public async Task<string> CreateUser()
    {
        string resultado = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencode"));
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:58663/api/createuser");
            User User = new User();
            User = SetUser();
            var formData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Username", User.Username));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", User.Password));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("EmailAddress", User.Email));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SignatureApp", User.SignatureApp));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("FechaRegistro", User.FechaRegistro));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ExpiracionToken", User.ExpiracionToken));
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                resultado = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                User = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(resultado);
            }
            else
            {
                resultado = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.ToString();
        }

        return resultado;
    }
```

Objeto `User`:

```
public class User
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string ExpiracionToken { get; set; }
        public string FechaRegistro { get; set; }
        public string SignatureApp { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Haz intentado de este enlace: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Answer (score 0):

Con este codigo pude enviar la peticion a la Api y que me respondiera correctamente :::

```
public async Task<string> CreateUser()
{
    string resultado = string.Empty;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:58663/api/CreateClient");
    User User = new User();
    User = SetUser(false);
    var formData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Username", User.Username));
    formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", User.Password));
    formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("EmailAddress", User.Email));
    formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SignatureApp", User.SignatureApp));
    formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("FechaRegistro", User.RegisteredDate.ToString()));
    formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ExpiracionToken", User.ExpiracionToken));
    request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
    var stringified = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(User);
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:58663/api/CreateClient", new StringContent(stringified, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        resultado = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        User = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(resultado);
    }
    else
    {
        resultado = response.StatusCode.ToString();
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Cuál de las dos es la respuesta correcta?